# Negative values returned by stafs struct's elements

Tags: c, stat

I am trying to retrieve file system information (with a C program) of an external SD card mounted on my Linux system.

According to the definition of **statfs** in **bits/statfs.h**

```
struct statfs
{
  __SWORD_TYPE f_type;
  __SWORD_TYPE f_bsize;
#ifndef __USE_FILE_OFFSET64
  __fsblkcnt_t f_blocks;
  __fsblkcnt_t f_bfree;
  __fsblkcnt_t f_bavail;
  __fsfilcnt_t f_files;
  __fsfilcnt_t f_ffree;
#else
  __fsblkcnt64_t f_blocks;
  __fsblkcnt64_t f_bfree;
  __fsblkcnt64_t f_bavail;
  __fsfilcnt64_t f_files;
  __fsfilcnt64_t f_ffree;
#endif
  __fsid_t f_fsid;
  __SWORD_TYPE f_namelen;
  __SWORD_TYPE f_frsize;
  __SWORD_TYPE f_flags;
  __SWORD_TYPE f_spare[4];
};
```

I wrote this little example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/statfs.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
   struct statfs buffer;

   unsigned long int total = 0;
   unsigned long int available = 0;

   statfs(argv[1], &buffer);

   total = buffer.f_blocks * buffer.f_frsize;
   available = buffer.f_bavail * buffer.f_frsize;

   printf("Total size of %s: %ld\n", argv[1], total);
   printf("Total free space: %ld\n", available);

   return 0;
}
```

But when the code is executed, I always retrieve negative values:

```
~$ ./fsStat /media/E4AD-87E9
Total size of /media/E4AD-87E9: -637362176
Total free space: -637366272
~$
```

While the oputput of **mount** and **df** is:

```
~$ mount
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /media/E4AD-87E9 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0077,codepage=cp437,iocharset=utf8,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks)

~$ df
Filesystem                                             1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mmcblk0p1                                           7766184        4   7766180   1% /media/E4AD-87E9
```

What is wrong with my C code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're trying print `long int` instead of `unsigned long int`. You need to change your `printf` statements as follows:

```
printf("Total size of %s: %lu\n", argv[1], total);
printf("Total free space: %lu\n", available);
```

Comment: OMG Sure ! Thank you Pooja !

Answer (score 0):

Code has another problem.

`__fsblkcnt_t` is not a standard type and has no `printf()` specifier.  At least in one [place](http://users.sosdg.org/~qiyong/mxr/source/sys/sys/ansi.h#L47) it is a 64-bit unsigned.

OP's code could be limiting by assigning to a narrower type as `unsigned long` is only certain to have at least 32-bits.

```
unsigned long int total = 0;
...
// Multiplication could overflow
// Assigment could narrow the product
total = buffer.f_blocks * buffer.f_frsize;
```

In places where code is not certain of the range of a type like `__fsblkcnt_t`, consider wider types and insuring the multiplication is also wide.  This will reduce the likelihood of overflow/narrowing.

```
unsigned long long total = 0;
...
total = 1ULL * buffer.f_blocks * buffer.f_frsize;
// use u for unsigned types, not d
printf("Total size of %s: %llu\n", argv[1], total);
```

---

For fun, considering [Moore's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law), the `total` size of an external SD card will exceed 64-bit about the year 2075.  YMMV

Code could use `uintmax_t` instead of `unsigned long long` and detect product overflow.  IMO `uintmax_t` will typically exceed 64-bit in a decade or so.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
uintmax_t total;
...
if (UINTMAX_MAX/buffer.f_blocks >= buffer.f_frsize) 
  total = UINTMAX_MAX;
else 
  total = UINTMAX_C(1) * buffer.f_blocks * buffer.f_frsize;
// use j with intmax_t/uintmax_t
printf("Total size of %s: %ju\n", argv[1], total);
```